# Store checked values from ajax pages

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Mostly i have 28 items, i used pagination and display in 3pages using Ajax
each page have 10 items, whatever i selected in check box it should display  values at bottom ,every thing is OK right now, but my problem is when i select  items in second page the previous list is disappearing , when i return back to fist page it is not showing previously selected items   .

iam not getting how to do this 
please help
thanks
 i used this jquery code to get checked values

```
function showValues() {
    var page = $("#pagedis").val();
    var fields = $(":input").serializeArray();
    $("#results_" + page).empty();
    jQuery.each(fields, function(i, field) {
        $("#results_" + page).append(field.value + "<br> ");
    });
}
```

i need the action like gmail if we select 3 items in one page ,4 items in 2nd page ,when i come back the checked value will never chage

Comment: Do you store your values in PHP sessions?

Comment: Agreed with Brice - if you're removing those elements from the DOM without persisting the previous states (using sessions for example) then the browser won't know to reapply the values when you add elements back into the DOM.

Comment: i given item name as value to checkbox 's ,so iam just displaying selected values in div

Answer (score 0):

1. do your checkboxes all have the same name?  If not, name them all the same.
2. make sure each checkbox has a unique value attribute
3. attach a handler to keep track of the checkboxes checked in an array

:

```
// global variable somewhere
var checkedBoxes = new Array();

$('input[name=theNameYouDefinedAbove]').click(function(event){
    checkedBoxes[$(this).val()] = $(this).is(':checked');
});
```

1. Now, when you paginate, just do this

:

```
$('input[name=theNameYouDefinedAbove]').each(function(index, checkbox){
    if (checkedBoxes[$(checkbox).val()]) {
        // NOTE: choose ONLY ONE!

        // for jQuery 1.6+
        $(checkbox).prop('checked', true);
        // for all jQuery
        $(checkbox).attr('checked', 'checked');
    }
});
```

Comment: while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($res2))
  { $menu_name=$row2['menu_name'];                                     echo "<input type='checkbox' name='check' value='".$menu_name."' id='".$menu_id."' onclick='showValues();' ".$dischk." />";}

Comment: I'm sorry, if you meant that to be a coherent thought, I'm afraid you failed.

Comment: Get rid of the onclick and hook it up in `$(document).ready(function() { ... here ... });`.  Did you have a question about my answer or anything?